# How to build a Monogame c# project on travis-ci

Tags: c#, travis-ci, monogame

The travis-ci build says

```
.. could not import "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets"
```

after moving this file to my project and editit the path from it in my .csproj file it says that the `mgcb.exe` cannot be found.

Where is the file in travis-ci or how can I add the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we need to install the monogame sdk

**Note: It need to be a version =<3.4 because of [this](http://community.monogame.net/t/pipeline-tool-dllnotfoundexception/6852)**

We need to edit or `.travis.yml` and install monogame and execute the `MGCB.exe`

```
language: csharp
solution: Project.sln
before_install:
  - wget http://www.monogame.net/releases/v3.4/MonoGame.Linux.zip
  - unzip MonoGame.Linux.zip
  - find * -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \; # lazy just make all executable
install:
  - sudo apt-get install -qq monodevelop libopenal-dev referenceassemblies-pcl ttf-mscorefonts-installer gtk-sharp2; # install needed packages for the monogame sdk
  - sudo ./generate.sh && yes Y|sudo ./monogame-linux.run; # install monogame sdk
script:
  - (cd Project/Content && mono /opt/monogame-pipeline/MGCB.exe /rebuild /@:"Content.mgcb" /outputDir:"../bin/Release/Content")
```

Also I used [an older version of the .targets file](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/1756c713b4aede3db5568f69012daf68be2d8c6a/MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline/MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets) and added before

```
<MonoGameContentBuilderExe Condition="'$(MonoGameContentBuilderExe)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MonoGame\v3.0\Tools\MGCB.exe</MonoGameContentBuilderExe>
```

this:

```
<MonoGameContentBuilderExe Condition=" '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' And Exists ('/opt/monogame-pipeline/MGCB.exe') ">/opt/monogame-pipeline/MGCB.exe</MonoGameContentBuilderExe>
```

For me xbuild doesn't automatically build this so I did it manually.